# Using ajax to post a view model which includes an IFormFile property in MVC Core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to post a simple viewmodel in MVC core using a jquery AJAX post, however the IFormFile property seems to be null on the model.

I have the following view model:

```
    [Required]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Owner")]
    public int DocumentOwner { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Document Type")]
    public int DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
```

I then use a jQuery ajax post inside a script at the bottom of my view:

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var model = $('form').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Client/AddDocument",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: model,
        success: function (message) {
            alert(message);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("There was error uploading files!");
        }
    });
});
```

The viewmodel is successfully passing the other values to the controller, however the file is coming through as null.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Change `var model = $('form').serialize();` to `var model = new FormData($('form').get(0));` - refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately the jQuery `serialize()` method will not include input file elements. So file user selected is not going to be included in the serialized value.

What you may do is, create a `FormData` object, append the files to that. You need to append the form field values as well to this same `FormData` object. You may simply loop through all the input field and add it. Also, in the ajax call, you need to specify `processData` and `contentType` property values to `false`

This should work

```
$(function () {

    $("form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formAction = $(this).attr("action");
        var fdata = new FormData();

        var fileInput = $('#File')[0];
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        fdata.append("File", file);

        // You can update the jquery selector to use a css class if you want
        $("input[type='text'").each(function (x, y) {
            fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: formAction ,
            data: fdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(result) {
            // do something with the result now
            console.log(result);
        });

    });

 });
```

The above code is reading the action attribute from the form ( which was submitted) and using that as the url for the ajax form submit.

```
@model YourViewModel
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home" method="post" >

    <label asp-for="DocumentOwner"></label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="DocumentOwner" />

    <label asp-for="DocumentTypeId"></label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="DocumentTypeId" />

    <label asp-for="File"></label>
    <input asp-for="File" />

    <input type="submit"  />
</form>
```

In your HttpPost action method, you can use the same view model as the parameter. The below sample code read the `File` property and save it to the `uploads` directory inside the `wwwroot` directory.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(YourViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (vm.File != null)
            {
                var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
                var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, GetUniqueFileName(vm.File.FileName));
                vm.File.CopyTo(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
                return Json(new {status = "success", message = "Successfully saved"});
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // handle what to do when model validation fails
        }
        return Json(new {status = "error", message = "something wrong!"});
    }
    private string GetUniqueFileName(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        return  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                  + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) 
                  + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was extremely useful.